# overbrace error: annotation text shows up below instead of above

Tags: overbrace

I am trying to use overbrace in a beamer presentation (compiled on Overleaf).
But overbrace is giving this unexpected result:

[image]

Notice that the text is being shown below everything, instead of above the brace. 
My code is:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

$\overbrace{3}_{bla}$
```

Any ideas on what can be happening?

Here is a full code reproducible example, error is in slide 2.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}
  \usecolortheme{default}
  \usefonttheme{default}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\title[Your Short Title]{my title}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  $\overbrace{3}_{student}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `$\overbrace{3}^{student}$` ?

Comment: yes, that is it. I did not notice. Please add as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You looking for `$\overbrace{3}^{student}$` (see `^`)

Command `\overbrace{...}` put only brace over `3`, position of index (label) is determined by `^˙ (for above brace) or`-`for below of`3`.

Similarly is with command `\underbrace{3}_{test}`, which put brace below `3` and `test` below braces, or `\underbrace{3}^{test}`, which put brace below `3` and `test` above it.

Shortly, those commands have sense in the following form:

```
\overbrace{3}^{student}
\underbrace{3}_{test}
```